# Tensorial notation for this quantum XOR circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Suppose I have this [quantum XOR circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[1,%22Sample1%22],[%22X%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22X%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22X%22,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,%22X%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22X%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22X%22,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[1,1,%22X%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22]]%7D); this is a quantum circuit for the classical XOR operation $$\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1'= x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3\oplus x_4,\\
x_2'=x_2\oplus x_3\oplus x_4\oplus x_5,\\
x_3'=x_3\oplus x_4\oplus x_5\oplus x_6.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now suppose I had $l$ quibts instead of $3$. What would be tensorial notation for this generalized circuit, what I think is $$U=\prod_{i=0}^{2}\prod_{k=0}^{q-1}I^{\otimes k}\otimes X\otimes I^{\otimes i}\otimes P_1\otimes I^{\otimes l-2-i-k}$$ is this the correct notation. The first $I$ tells how many qubits will be unaltered, the second $I$ adjusts the correct control, $P_1$ is the projection operator, and last $I$ does nothing on the remaining qubits. Ignore the part of this operator when the state is $0$ i.e. projection operator $P_0$ is omitted.

Comment: You cannot just ignore $P_0$, if you do your operation is neither unitary nor entangling!